# Manually select which GPU is power saving/high performance

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I have two monitors connected to two different GPU's and I would like the load to be splitted like they are connected. The problem is that is not the case, everything (Video decoding) is calculated by main GPU although it is displayed on second monitor. There are many similar problems in the internet, yet none addresses problems I have.

The outcome I would like to achieve is impossible as far as google questions refer to, although maybe some software can achieve this?

The exact problem I want to refer in this question to is related to [selecting which GPU to use per app](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/select-gpu-to-use-by-specific-applications/eb671f52-5c24-428d-a7a0-02a36e91ee2f). This solution would be enough if not for the fact that [Windows says the best GPU for power saving and max performance it the same GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvcZN.png), not allowing me to use any available solution to the problem.

So, I want to ask two questions:

- is it possible to enforce rendering with GPU that monitor is connected to?
- can I manually tell Windows which GPU would be better for power saving or another profile?

Edit: my graphic cards are GTX 1060 and GT 730, one monitor connected to each GPU.

Comment: I think you're trying to apply concept/procedures of a laptop with hybrid iGPU+dGPU to a desktop with 2 dGPUs. It isn't applicable and with such setup it makes no sense to speak of "power saving". The GTX1060 has surely the higher performance and likely also the better energy efficiency so Windows is right.

Comment: I undestand your reasosing and that is absolutely correct, but that does not address the question. I have the real need for a feature/capability I described and yet I cannot find solution for that

Comment: If you have a real need (LOL) for such feature use a laptop with hybrid graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This similar question has an answer, of sorts:

[Windows 10; Manually select power saving and performance GPU](https://superuser.com/questions/1538875/windows-10-manually-select-power-saving-and-performance-gpu)

Summary:  Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 20190 has options that will address this.

Comment: Although I accepted this answer, this is not in Windows (normal) release yet

Comment: Update: This is supported in Windows 11 (only external links available) - https://www.windowslatest.com/2021/06/23/windows-11-includes-support-for-wddm-3-0-display-driver-model/

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty ugly workaround for this.

Windows 10 seems to always choose the same card as both High performance and Power Saving mode.

Whenever a program is launched, it's bound to the currently selected GPU until it is closed (switching GPUs at runtime for something like a game would be a nightmare so this is a safe bet)

If no monitors are connected to a GPU and it was previously the primary, windows will switch the primary to the next GPU with atleast one monitor connected to it.

This means you can disconnect the monitor attached to the GPU windows defaults to, launch a program that you want bound to the secondary GPU, then reconnect the monitor once its started.

Programs already running on the GPU with no monitors will continue to run fine.

As a side note, my monitor acts as disconnected as soon as I power it off so this process isn't that painful.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 it seems to be possible to force GPUs to be the powersaving and performance GPU respectively via a registry hack:

1. Navigate Regedit to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}`
2. Identify the four digit subfolders that contain your desired GPUs (e.g. by the key `DriverDesc` inside)
3. Create a new `DWORD` key inside both four digit folders, name it `EnableMsHybrid`

   - Set it to a value of `1` for the performance GPU
   - Set it to a value of `2` for the powersave GPU
4. Reboot. The settings app should then offer the set GPUs for per app graphics settings.

Caveats of this method:

- It only works with 2 GPUs, any additional GPUs are still wasted
- The setting is only applied to DirectX and Vulkan, not OpenGL

  - At least for Nvidia Cards, the OpenGL GPU can be selected through their control panel app
- The default GPU cannot be selected via the Settings app, it's still the performance GPU

Comment: Sadly, this did not work for me in Win10 22H2 19045.3324 with an A380 and a RTX 3070 Ti.