# Windows 10; Manually select power saving and performance GPU

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu

I have Two discrete graphics cards, each with a monitor attached. My main screen which is used for gaming running from a 2080ti and a second touch screen running from a 1080ti which is mainly used for skype and browser activity.

Windows 10 recently got the ability on desktop machines to allow on a program by program basis to select which GPU application visuals are run from. (settings->system->display->graphics settings)

[image: Setting GPU afinity for skype]

**My question is**: How do I set which GPU is assigned to the 'power saving gpu' and 'high performance gpu' categories?

Comment: Microsoft is testing a feature implementation for this in insider build 20190. See https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/08/12/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20190/

Comment: I just added a workaround to a similar question here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1489428/manually-select-which-gpu-is-power-saving-high-performance/1764332#1764332

Comment: I just added more of an actual answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1784409/69555

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually select which GPU is power saving/high performance](https://superuser.com/questions/1489428/manually-select-which-gpu-is-power-saving-high-performance)